# Can I use multiple different Stripe customer portals for one Stripe account in an application?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to add two separate customer portals per Stripe account in an application. How should I do this?

I searched through Stripe documentation, but have had no luck yet. Since I'm new to Stripe I need help with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up only one Customer Portal Link through [Dashboard settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/portal), but you can use API to create many [configurations](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/integrate-customer-portal#configure) as you need (for example, configuration 1 enables subscription update, and configuration 2 enables subscription cancel).

After that can you call the Customer Portals API to create a portal session with a [configuration](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-configuration), and your customer can visit its [url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/session#portal_session_object-url) and access the portal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question, Can I use the API to create two configurations (for example, configuration 1 for product 1, and configuration 2 for product 2 which is totally different and separate from product 1) and two configurations can have a separate billing cycle, separate invoice, and separate charge?

Comment: Yes you can specify the list of products that support subscription updates (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-products), so that your customer can only choose to update to one of the products in this list when visiting customer portal.

Comment: About the second part, I don't think the customer is able to change billing cycle, invoice or change through portal. You might want to call Subscription update API from your backend to make changes to the subscription.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I'll try what you have said.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many custom portal configurations you can setup? Do they expire? 

I guess we can just create one every time one is needed, but it seems like that will create a lot of objects out there... somewhere...